# не получается правильно собрать OpenCV + GStreamer (MinGW, Windows)

Tags: opencv, mingw, gstreamer

Уже долгое время пытаюсь собрать OpenCV + GStreamer. При запуске тестового пайплайна:

```
  cv::VideoCapture cap = cv::VideoCapture(" autovideosrc ! videoconvert ! appsink0 ", cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

Получаю следующую ошибку (см.ниже). В чем может быть проблема? компилятор 32 битный, gstreamer тоже, все пути в path прописаны. На линуксе всё успешно собиралось и работало, а тут я уже не знаю, что я делаю не так.
win7, mingw 7.3.0, opencv 4.1.0, gstreamer 1.16.0

```
 0:00:00.040498363  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:793:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: module_open failed: 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdecklink.dll': РќРµ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅР° СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅР°СЏ РїСЂРѕС†РµРґСѓСЂР°.

    (untitled2.exe:6904): GStreamer-WARNING **: 02:29:33.412: Failed to load plugin 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdecklink.dll': 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdecklink.dll': Не найдена указанная процедура.
    0:00:00.061620856  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:793:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: module_open failed: 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopenh264.dll': РќРµ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅР° СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅР°СЏ РїСЂРѕС†РµРґСѓСЂР°.

    (untitled2.exe:6904): GStreamer-WARNING **: 02:29:33.432: Failed to load plugin 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopenh264.dll': 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopenh264.dll': Не найдена указанная процедура.
    0:00:00.072668621  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:793:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: module_open failed: 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsoundtouch.dll': РќРµ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅР° СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅР°СЏ РїСЂРѕС†РµРґСѓСЂР°.

    (untitled2.exe:6904): GStreamer-WARNING **: 02:29:33.442: Failed to load plugin 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsoundtouch.dll': 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsoundtouch.dll': Не найдена указанная процедура.
    0:00:00.088487674  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:793:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: module_open failed: 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsrt.dll': РќРµ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅР° СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅР°СЏ РїСЂРѕС†РµРґСѓСЂР°.

    (untitled2.exe:6904): GStreamer-WARNING **: 02:29:33.465: Failed to load plugin 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsrt.dll': 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsrt.dll': Не найдена указанная процедура.
    0:00:00.089972159  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:793:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: module_open failed: 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsttaglib.dll': РќРµ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅР° СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅР°СЏ РїСЂРѕС†РµРґСѓСЂР°.

    (untitled2.exe:6904): GStreamer-WARNING **: 02:29:33.465: Failed to load plugin 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsttaglib.dll': 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsttaglib.dll': Не найдена указанная процедура.
    0:00:00.097988553  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:793:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: module_open failed: 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstwebrtcdsp.dll': РќРµ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅР° СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅР°СЏ РїСЂРѕС†РµРґСѓСЂР°.

    (untitled2.exe:6904): GStreamer-WARNING **: 02:29:33.475: Failed to load plugin 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstwebrtcdsp.dll': 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstwebrtcdsp.dll': Не найдена указанная процедура.
    0:00:00.107822720  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                 filesrc gstfilesrc.c:533:gst_file_src_start:<source> error: No such file "C:\Users\Shmeisser\Documents\build-untitled2-Desktop_Qt_5_9_4_MinGW_32bit-Debug\ autovideosrc ! videoconvert ! appsink0"
    0:00:00.107911655  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3469:gst_base_src_start:<source> error: Failed to start
    0:00:00.108341459  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                 filesrc gstfilesrc.c:533:gst_file_src_start:<source> error: No such file "C:\Users\Shmeisser\Documents\build-untitled2-Desktop_Qt_5_9_4_MinGW_32bit-Debug\ autovideosrc ! videoconvert ! appsink0"
    0:00:00.108391029  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3469:gst_base_src_start:<source> error: Failed to start
    0:00:00.108489004  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                 filesrc gstfilesrc.c:533:gst_file_src_start:<source> error: No such file "C:\Users\Shmeisser\Documents\build-untitled2-Desktop_Qt_5_9_4_MinGW_32bit-Debug\ autovideosrc ! videoconvert ! appsink0"
    0:00:00.108535367  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3469:gst_base_src_start:<source> error: Failed to start
    0:00:00.108575898  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3824:gst_base_src_activate_push:<source> Failed to start in push mode
    0:00:00.108603015  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                GST_PADS gstpad.c:1142:gst_pad_set_active:<source:src> Failed to activate pad
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На всякий случай всем, кто столкнется с данной проблемой. Собрать под win7/win10 OpenCV + GStreamer компилятором MinGW у меня так и не получилось. Пробовал на множестве разных машин, копался в настройках сборки, проблему обнаружить не удалось. Наиболее простым вариантом решения проблемы является сборка компилятором mscv 15/17 (то что проверил лично). Собирается без каких-либо проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
cv::VideoCapture cap = cv::VideoCapture("autovideosrc ! videoconvert ! appsink", cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

Просто appsink, а не appsink0. По умолчанию appsink как раз к нему должен линковаться https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.1.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp#L552

Comment: я по-всякому пробовал. так тоже не работает. тут проблема скорее в том, что я либо неправильно собрал, либо что-то не так линкуется. более того, "the appsink name should be either 'appsink0'" подразумевает как раз то, что нужно писать appsink0, а не appsink